# Which of the following answers actually calculates the surface area of the Steinmetz solid?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

To calculate the value of the surface area of the Steinmetz solid generated by two cylinders of radius 1, in [Surface Area of Two Cylinders Calculus 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/755287/surface-area-of-two-cylinders-calculus-3/755408#755408) the answer is proposed to be 8, while in [Intersection of two cylinders](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2599749/intersection-of-two-cylinders) the answer is said to be 16. Since both answers are already accepted, naturally one of the two must be wrong, but I can't figure out which one and why. After a little searching it seems to me that the correct answer really is 16, but I can't figure out why the answer that gives 8 is wrong. Could you please help me find the error in his solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me repeat whole task here: so, we have two cylinders
$$y^2 + z^2 = 1 \\
y^2 + x^2 = 1$$

and we would like to calculate surface area of created by them bounded figure, known as [Steinmetz solid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinmetz_solid) (bicylinder).

One way is consider projection on plane $Oxy$ and count integral as it is partly done on  [Surface Area of Two Cylinders Calculus 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/755287/surface-area-of-two-cylinders-calculus-3/755408#755408),  for $z=\pm\sqrt{1-y^2}$ i.e.
$$2\int_{-1}^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^\sqrt{1-y^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}dxdy = 8$$
**But**, this is not enough, because by this integral we calculate only surface area for floor and ceiling with respect to $Oxy$, but forget walls for our figure. To obtain surface area for walls we can consider them, for example, as floor and ceiling, given by $x=\pm\sqrt{1-y^2}$,  with respect to $Oyz$ plane. Now we obtain exactly same as above integral, but with respect to
$y,z$ variables

$$2\int_{-1}^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^\sqrt{1-y^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}dzdy = 8$$
So, at last, we have $16$ for whole surface.

This, of course, can be done by considering projection with respect to $Oxz$ plane, which way is fulfilled on [Intersection of two cylinders](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2599749/intersection-of-two-cylinders)   and have same answer $16$.

Comment: Thank you for everything!